# How to use fpdf in wordpress plugin to edit pdf template?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, fpdf

I have a pdf template in media library, I want to edit the pdf with client's details whenever a client make's a purchase, and then attach the pdf in an email that will be sent to client by `wp_mail()` function. I have already attached the pdf and used the `wp_mail` function to send it, the only thing I am not able to do is edit the pdf with the respective client's details, I want the details to come from database automatically, someone please help..